# How to setOnEditorActionListener with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

So I have this Java code:

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            doSomething();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

I've managed to get this (which I'm not even sure it's the right way):

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener() { v, actionId, event ->
      if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
          doSomething()
      } else {
      }
}
```

But I get an error `Error:(26, 8) Type mismatch: inferred type is kotlin.Unit but kotlin.Boolean was expected`

So how is such event handler written in Kotlin?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The [`onEditorAction`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener.html#onEditorAction) returns a `Boolean` while your Kotlin lambda returns `Unit`. Change it to i.e:

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, event ->
      if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
          doSomething()
          true
      } else {
          false
      }
}
```

[The documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expressions-and-anonymous-functions) on lambda expressions and anonymous functions is a good read.

Comment: will you please tell me `{ v, actionId, event ->` which topic is it ?

Comment: @sushildlh there you go.

Comment: @sushildlh not sure what you mean. There's [anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko) and [android extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html) that you may find useful.

Answer (score 11):

Kotlin would be great with **when** keyword instead of using **if else**

To me, the following code is prettier:

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, event ->
  when(actionId){
      EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE -> {
            doSomething()
            true
      }
      else -> false
  }
}
```

p/s: The code of @Pier not working because of a expression is required on the right side of lambda. So, we have to use true/false instead of return true/false

Answer (score 5):

Write simple Kotlin extention for EditText

```
fun EditText.onAction(action: Int, runAction: () -> Unit) {
    this.setOnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, event ->
        return@setOnEditorActionListener when (actionId) {
            action -> {
                runAction.invoke()
                true
            }
            else -> false
        }
    }
}
```

and use it

```
/**
 * use EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE constant
 * or something another from
 * @see android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo
 */
edit_name.onAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
  // code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use another form:

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener { _, actionId, _ ->

        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            doSomething()
            true
        } else {
            false
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
et.setOnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, event ->
            when(actionId){
                EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE -> {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                true
            }

            EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Next", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                true
            }
            else -> false
        }
    }
```